# Bash dynamic var name assignment and access

Tags: bash

In the following `bash` function I would like a new variable called `PASS` to be created on the first `$2` occurrence and then have the new `$PASS` variable to be tested in the second `$2` occurrence.

```
function ask() {
    while read -s -p "Type your $1 and press enter: " $2 && [[ -z "${$2// }" ]]; do
        echoboldred -e "\n${1^} can't be blank."
    done
}

ask password PASS
```

Comment: Don't use ALL_UPPERCASE variables.

Comment: Inian I dont agree at all. First of all I've never stated my code wasn't working neither why. Second y thing the goal was pretty clear. Anyway i appreciate your time but I don't understand the down vote. Ianos gave me the exact solution I was looking for so i cannot agree with you at all. melpomene, I thought using uppercase variable names was a good practice in BASH.

Comment: @user846226: I did not down-vote your question

Comment: Ad: `I thought using uppercase variable names was a good practice in BASH`. No, it isn't. UPPERCASE variables are "reserved" for the exported variables, like: `HOME`, `SHELL`, `TERM` and like. Therefore, the good practice is *not using* UPPERCASE variables in your script.

Comment: Note that your design is flawed: if a user interrupts the `read` statement with `^D` (control-D), or if `read` fails for whatever reason, then you'll return from function `ask` with an invalid password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `${$2// }`.
To perform the `//` on the variable whose name is in `$2`,
the correct syntax is `${!2// }`.

```
while read -s -p "Type your $1 and press enter: " "$2" && [[ -z "${!2// }" ]]; do
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I already read some docs where they talk about it but didn't noticed the trick was on using ! symbol. You made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use nameref declared with `local -n` instead of parameter indirection, it might make your code more readable:

```
ask() {
   local -n foo=$2
   while read -srp "Type your $1 and press enter: " foo && ! [[ $foo ]]; do
      printf -- "\n%s can't be blank.\n" "${1^}"
   done
}

ask password pass
```

**Don't** declare your functions with the `function` keyword and it's also advisable to use `-r` option with `read` in case your password has backslashes in it:

```
-r      do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

Comment: Note that namerefs require `bash` 4.3 or later, although it is increasingly likely to be in use (having been released nearly 4 years ago).